# A combo box that has to be filter the same data in that field

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to make a combo box (drop-down box) that would include Cities
and `City1` is placed multiple times likewise `City2`, `City3`, `City4`... etc.
`ComboBox` should show the filtered `City1`, `City2`, one after one, without repeating the cities name again.

If I select `City1` from the list then it shows only the students details for the selected city.

Can this be done? I have been trying to do this for at least 2 days but no luck

Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Read [ask] and improve question (edit) E.g what have you tried so far. And it is always obvious to copy your questions title to a search engine.

Comment: Show code! Do some tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_combo_box.htm To show no duplicates search for "ms access combobox no duplicates".

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Is it two columns of data, one being a city name (Denver, Detroit, Paris,...) and the other being a grouping (City1, City2, City2, City3...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'm going to use VBA for this. To access the VBA menu in your Access file, press ALT + F11.

Secondly, I can't give you a full tutorial on VBA here. You'll have to work out any kinks yourself.

I have two tables

DimCity:

```
| Field Name | Data Type  |
---------------------------
| CityIndex  | Short Text | * Unique index for each city; Foreign key in DimStudent table
| CityKey    | Short Text | * Will serve to make City1, City2, etc
| City       | Short Text | * Name of each city
```

DimStudent:

```
| Field Name | Data Type  |
---------------------------
| StudentKey | Short Text | * Unique key for each student
| CityIndex  | Short Text | * CityIndex is a foreign key here
| LastName   | Short Text | * Student last name
| FirstName  | Short Text | * Student first name
```

Create a new query that will be used as the base of our form.  You'll also make a custom column called `CityID`.

The query for that is:

```
SELECT DimStudent.StudentKey
, DimCity.CityIndex
, DimStudent.LastName
, DimStudent.FirstName
, DimCity.CityKey
, DimCity.City, "City" & CStr([CityKey]) AS CityID -- Convert the CityKey to a string
FROM DimCity
INNER JOIN DimStudent ON DimCity.CityIndex = DimStudent.CityIndex;
```

Then, create a **split** form, not the default one they give you. Also, set the split window to be at the bottom (should be under Form -> Properties -> Format -> Split Form Orientation).  The ComboBox will have two columns from the query we created:

```
SELECT vwTerritoryStudent.CityKey
, vwTerritoryStudent.CityID
FROM vwTerritoryStudent
GROUP BY vwTerritoryStudent.CityKey
, vwTerritoryStudent.CityID;
```

The form query is (I named my query `vwTerritoryStudent`):

```
SELECT vwTerritoryStudent.StudentKey
, vwTerritoryStudent.FirstName
, vwTerritoryStudent.LastName
, vwTerritoryStudent.CityKey
FROM vwTerritoryStudent;
```

The form will have the ComboBox and a few other TextBox objects, which you can set as invisible later on:

[image]

Name the ComboBox something interesting. I went with `City_combo`.

Open your VBA editor (ALT + F11) and paste the following into the Form__[name of your form] module.  My module is `Form_StudentForm`.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private filter_str As String ' Create a local variable to keep things simple

Private Sub City_combo_AfterUpdate()
' After update on whatever your combobox with 'CityID' values is

' Call our MyFilter subprocess
Call MyFilter

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Close()
' Clear up the filter when closing the form
' This is a good habit to get into unless the end user wants
' to have the form filtered the exact same way when they reopen it.
With Me
    .Form.Filter = ""
    .Form.FilterOn = False
End With
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
' On load action

' Call our MyFilter subprocess
Call MyFilter

End Sub


Public Sub MyFilter()

' Call SetFilter evaluation subprocess
Call SetFilter

' Evaluate results of SetFilter subprocess
With Me
    .Form.Filter = filter_str ' Set filter to whatever the module-level filter_str variable is
    If Len(Nz(filter_str)) > 0 Then
        .FilterOn = True
    Else
        .FilterOn = False ' Set FilterOn = False if no filter value set.
    End If
End With

End Sub

Public Sub SetFilter()
' Determine if our combobox contains a value
' if it does, set our module-level filter string to
' the CityKey value
With Me
    If Len(Nz(.City_combo.Value)) > 0 Then
        filter_str = "[CityKey] = " & .City_combo.Value
    Else
        filter_str = ""
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

There's some commentary in there to help you along.

Side note: If you're going to do a lot of VBA, get familiar with the Compile function in the VBA editor:

[image]

Anyway, if everything works, then you should be able to select a CityID from the ComboBox and have your form filter to those records:

[image]

After selecting a CityID:

[image]

You can add that City field to bring in the City Name, too.

[image]

You can add a button to clear the filter or just delete the contents of the ComboBox to get all the records again.

That should probably do it.  if you have any issues, see if you can try to figure them out first, but drop me a line and I'll try to respond as quickly as I can.

Comment: Some suggestions: 1, If you pamper new users, they will expect that next time too, instead of learning to solve problems them selfes (effort by OP hardly noticeable). 2.In code: using call is obsolete. `Me.Filter`is a string and can never get Null (omit Nz), +1 for the`Len > 0`pattern. You can simplify to`Me.FilterOn = Len(Me.Filter) > 0` . Instead of a filter, you can add the combobox to the query criteria, like `WHERE CityKey = Forms("StudentForm").Controls("City_combo").Value Or Forms("StudentForm").Controls("City_combo").Value Is Null`what shows all records if combo not selected.

Comment: Ah, nice tips! Yeah, I hadn't done VBA in a while and thought this would be interesting to tackle.  I tried using that WHERE part directly in the SQL query, but it was acting up, so I took the simple route.  I'll have to remember your suggestion for next time.